# How can I chain asynchronous Firebase updates in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

React & Firebase newbie here. I have a React component that needs to look up some stuff in Firebase before rendering. My database design requires first getting the correct doohick ids and subsequently looking up the doohick details, but I'm not sure how to do that with the asynchronous nature of Firebase database access. This doesn't work:

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${username}/doohick-ids`).on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({doohick_ids: doohick_ids});
        });

        this.state.doohick_ids.forEach(id => {  
            // ids don't actually exist at this point outside the callback
            firebase.database().ref(`/doohick-details/${id}`).on('value', snapshot => {
                // update state
            });         
        });

    render() {
        if (this.state.doohick-ids) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // render the Doohick subcomponents
        } 
    }
}
```

I can think of a few solutions here, but none that I like. What's the recommended way to chain together Firebase calls, or perhaps redesign this to eliminate the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the `forEach` be in a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook? In your case the `forEach` will run before the database callback fires, operating on an empty array (or null, depending on how you set up your state). Using `componentDidUpdate` should only run your code if you state has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should split one component `Widget` to two `WidgetList` and `WidgetItem`.

#### `WidgetItem`

subscribe and unsubscribe to `firebase.database().ref(/doohick-details/${id})`

```
class WidgetItem extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
    this.dbRef = null;

    this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    this.dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`/doohick-details/${id}`);

    this.dbRef.on('value', this.onValueChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.dbRef.off('value', this.onValueChange);
  }

  onValueChange(dataSnapshot) {
    // update state
    this.setState(dataSnapshot);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</pre>
    );
  }
}
```

#### WidgetList

subscribe and unsubscribe to `firebase.database().ref(/users/${username}/doohick-ids)`

```
class WidgetItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { doohick_ids: [] };
    this.dbRef = null;

    this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Note: I've just copied your example. `username` is undefined.
    this.dbRef = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${username}/doohick-ids`);

    this.dbRef.on('value', this.onValueChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.dbRef.off('value', this.onValueChange);
  }

  onValueChange(dataSnapshot) {
    this.setState({ doohick_ids: dataSnapshot });
  }

  render() {
    const { doohick_ids } = this.state;

    if (doohick_ids.length === 0) {
      return 'Loading...';
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {doohick_ids.map(id => <WidgetItem key={id} id={id} />)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And code that requires the data from the database needs to be *inside* the callback that is invoked when that data is available. Code outside of the callback is not going to have the right data.

So:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${username}/doohick-ids`).on('value', snapshot => {
    this.setState({doohick_ids: doohick_ids});
    doohick_ids.forEach(id => {  
        // ids don't actually exist at this point outside the callback
        firebase.database().ref(`/doohick-details/${id}`).on('value', snapshot => {
            // update state
        });         
    });
});
```

There's many optimizations possible here, but they all boil down to the code being inside the callback and updating the state when a value comes from the database.